# How exactly do you use find that this series is convergent using the ratio test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n-1}}{(2n^2 + n + 1)^{(n+1)/2}}$$
So I already know that to find whether this is a convergent or divergent series you have to use the ratio test however I am stuck at how you solve the $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ part. If anyone can explain that to me in detail thanks a lot.

Comment: The root test seems easier to use here honestly. Also, there are situations where these tests fail to give any conclusion, when you find $1$ as the limit, so you do not always "have" to use them.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: What expression have you obtained by ratio test?

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n= \frac{n^{n-1}}{(2n^2 + n + 1)^{(n+1)/2}}$$
Take logarithms
$$\log(a_n)=(n-1)\log(n)-\frac{n+1}2 \log(2n^2+n+1)$$ By Taylor
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{2} n \log (2)+\frac{1}{4} (-8 \log (n)-1-2 \log
   (2))-\frac{7}{16 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Apply is a second time for $a_{n+1}$ and continue with Taylor
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-\frac{\log (2)}{2}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{23}{16n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Now
$$\frac{a_{n+1} }{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}+\frac{55}{16 \sqrt{2}
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the ratio test, observe that $$0<\frac {n^{n-1}}{(2n^2+n+1)^{(n+1)/2}}=$$ $$=\frac {(n^2)^{(n-1)/2}}{(2n^2+n+1)^{(n-1)/2}}\cdot \frac {1}{2n^2+n+1}<$$ $$<\frac {(n^2)^{(n-1)/2}}{(2n^2)^{(n-1)/2}}\cdot \frac {1}{2n^2+n+1}=$$ $$=\frac {1}{2^{(n-1)/2}}\cdot \frac {1}{2n^2+n+1}<$$ $$<\frac {1}{2^{(n-1)/2}}.$$

6